# aws quicksight - failed to satisfy constraint: Specified resource is not reachable in this region ('us-east-1')

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-quicksight

Using the nodejs  AWS SDK i'm trying to update my quickSight DataSet with a csv file in S3 bucket.
When calling the AWS quicksight update-data-set command(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/quicksight/update-data-set.html) I'm getting the following error:

**'physicalTableMap.string.member.s3Source.dataSourceArn' failed to satisfy constraint: Specified resource is not reachable in this region ('us-east-1')**

I checked my quicksight region and s3 bucket region all set to 'us-east-1', so not sure why it's still complaining about region? IAM is also set to us-east-1

the dataSourceArn i'm passing is the arn for the S3 csv file.

**Code**

```
const updateDataSetParams: UpdateDataSetRequest = {
  AwsAccountId: awsAccountId /* required */,
  DataSetId: getEnvironmentKeyValue("AWS_PERMISSIONS_DATA_SET_ID") /* required */,
  ImportMode: "SPICE" /* required */,
  Name: getEnvironmentKeyValue("AWS_PERMISSIONS_DATA_SET_DISPLAY_NAME") /* required */,
  PhysicalTableMap: {
    string: {
      S3Source: {
        DataSourceArn: getEnvironmentKeyValue("AWS_PERMISSIONS_S3_DATA_SOURCE_ARN") /* required */,
        InputColumns: [
          /* required */
          {
            Name: "UserName" /* required */,
            Type: "STRING" /* required */
          },
          {
            Name: "CompanyName" /* required */,
            Type: "STRING" /* required */
          },
          {
            Name: "BranchIds" /* required */,
            Type: "STRING" /* required */
          }
          /* more items */
        ],
        UploadSettings: {
          ContainsHeader: true,
          Delimiter: ",",
          Format: "CSV"
          //      StartFromRow: 2
        }
      }
    }
  }
};

const updateDataSet = await quicksight.updateDataSetAsync(updateDataSetParams);
```

p:s , I manage to call other quicksight commands like create-namespace and create-user which all work fine.  Only when I try to update the dataset.

Comment: Could you check from AWS CLI `aws s3 ls` that the bucket exists and is accessible? You might want to try using the QuickSight IAM user profile when you check this.

Comment: Hi, Yes bucket exists and is public access.